# jQuery inserted into pages

Tags: javascript, jquery

I insert a line into the header of a page such as facebook

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://websitename.com/jquery.js"></script>
```

Now that page has jquery, the issue is that now that page is now messed up.
Messed up in the sense that animations and events dont fire off for menus and such.
The facebook account button on the top right no longer expands.
How can I include jquery onto a page without breaking that page's own jquery/plugins/javascript?

noConflict does not work, the issue is simply including jquery on the page. Not using it.

I made a firefox addon that requires jquery to be on the page.
So it inserts it and works well, but breaks certain websites by simply including it.

Comment: why/when/where would you ever do this?

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [.noConflict()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/)

Comment: Ive tried that, no conflicted is for when you use your own jquery code and it can conflict because of the $ symbol. But just including the jquery like that breaks the page. Not because im using jquery.

Comment: I didn't even know that exist! thanks, it will help me in some future projects for sure

Comment: @Drake, it's for when you're using another javascript framework that uses $ (like mootools I believe). Do you really have no other javascript on your page that could be conflicting with the jQuery inclusion?

Answer (score 0):

Well the facebook site probably has a different definition for the `$` variable which you overwrote when you added jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

You may take a look at the [following article](http://docs.jquery.com/Using_jQuery_with_Other_Libraries) about using jQuery with other libraries.